# How to add a method with multiple parameters to the selector of a button

Tags: button, methods, selector

I get this error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException when I try to add a method with multiple parameters to the selector of a button

[viewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loadDocument: inView:) withObject:cerereIndemnizatie.fisier withObject:self.myWebview forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

This is the method

```
  -(void)loadDocument:(NSString*)documentName inView:(UIWebView*)webView
{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documentName ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you think you can do this or why would `UIButton` respond to the `addTarget:selector:withObject:withObject:forControlEvents:` selector... (Seriously, don't guess, read the documentation...)

You can achieve similar behavior by using associated objects:

```
UIButton *btn = // create the button
objc_setAssociatedObject(btn, "firstObject", someObject, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
objc_setAssociatedObject(btn, "secondObject", otherObject, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)click:(UIButton *)sender
{
    id first = objc_getAssociatedObject(btn, "firstObject");
    id second = objc_setAssociatedObject(btn, "secondObject");
    // etc.
}
```